# listening for metamask popup to complete script with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, metamask

hey I am trying to create a application in node js utilizing puppeteer and dappeteer that signs off any metamask transaction that pops up in the browser using the predetermined settings in the script. what i am having trouble with is listening for the metamask popup for the transaction confirmation then queuing the rest of the puppeteer script to complete the transaction. is there anyway i can listen for the event of metamask prompt?

it should wait for the user to trigger the metamask popup manually prior to attempting to sign off the transaction.

any help would be great!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You would have to count windows and poll for when there's a new one. Using page.waitForTarget won't work since it's an extension and not a regular page.